# How to display desired text in hyperlink using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I have displayed my hyperlink in the column E as shown
`\\maroon\cgm images\mech.pdf`

But I want to display only `mech.pdf` in the cell how to modify my code.

my code used for displaying above hyperlink is shown below:

```
str = "\\maroon\CGM Images\" & pn & ".pdf"
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Range("e" & i), str
```

In this I want to show only `pn` & `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `TextToDisplay`

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("e" & i), Address:=Str, TextToDisplay:=pn & ".pdf"
```

Sometimes the [Excel VBA reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861528.aspx) is indeed helpful to find out on your own how functions and methods work: [Hyperlinks.Add Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score -2):

If you have

> \maroon\cgm images\mech.pdf

in a cell and you wanna get only the name of the pdf with ".pdf" you can do the next code:

```
Dim spliter() as String
Dim str_pdf as String

str = \maroon\cgm images\mech.pdf ' Cells(a,b).value
spliter = Split(str, " ") 'To do the first split (You can delete ', " "' )
spliter = Split(spliter(1), "\")
'Now spliter(1) == mech.pdf so...
str_pdf = spliter(1) ' spliter(0) == images , spliter(1) == mech.pdf
```

Comment: You should read his question. This was not what he asked for.